# How to align tabs of tabpanel on center on Extjs 4?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs4, tabpanel

It's possible to align tabs of tabpanel on center? I want align tabs on center without using margins. Have any property for this? You can see in image to understand what i need.

[image: TabPanel]

Comment: why can't you use border layout for this...

Answer (score 4):

When defining your TabPanel, use this:

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    tabBar: {
        layout: { pack: 'center' }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in 4.1.3.  Unless this was a bug that was fixed between 4.1.1 and 4.1.3, I would check that you don't have any typos or duplicate properties.

Comment: Can confirm - does not work on 4.1.1. Neither does:
                            tabBar: {
                                layout: { type: 'hbox', pack: 'center', align: 'middle' }
                            },